# Eigenvalues of a linear transformation in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Let $T: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ be the rotation of $\mathbb{R^3}$ around the $x_{2}$-axis by 90 degrees. Find all real eigenvalues of T without computing its standard matrix. Explain your reasoning.

So, for this problem, I initially thought this might be some interesting application of one of the properties of determinants, specifically the property $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$, with the $x_{2}$ rotational matrix in $\mathbb{R^3}$, with the following as $A$:\begin{vmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & 0 & -\sin(\theta)\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta)
\end{vmatrix}
and some matrix with variables being $B$.  
 
When that didn't work for me, I tried to simply solve for the eigenvalues after applying the transformation, by doing:

$\det\left(\begin{vmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & 0 & -\sin(\theta)\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta)
\end{vmatrix}*\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c\\ 
d & e & f\\ 
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & \lambda & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{vmatrix}\right)$

But I think I'm simply overcomplicating it now. Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  So the $x_2$-axis is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$

Comment: By definition of eigenvector $Ax = \lambda x$. It is given that $x_2$ is axis of rotation, so only a vector in direction of $x_2$ can be eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm confused. If you are searching the eigenvalues, you have to solve $$Tx=\lambda x$$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $x\neq 0$. This is equivalent to find $\lambda$ such that$$\begin{vmatrix}
\cos(\theta)-\lambda & 0 & -\sin(\theta)\\
0 & 1-\lambda & 0\\
\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta)-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=0$$ then $$(\cos(\theta)-\lambda)[(1-\lambda)(\cos(\theta)-\lambda)]+\sin(\theta)[\sin(\theta)(1-\lambda)]=0$$ $$(1-\lambda)(\cos(\theta)-\lambda)^2+(1-\lambda)\sin^2(\theta)=0$$ $$(1-\lambda)[(\cos(\theta)-\lambda)^2+\sin^2(\theta)]=0$$ $$(1-\lambda)(\lambda^2-2\lambda\cos(\theta)+1)=0$$
and you know that $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Maybe this could help you.

Comment: Does that still works if I want to find the eigenvalues after the transformation has occurred?